# Saga for constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

```
const SYSTEM_DATA = {
    GENDER: [
        { value: 'male', label: 'Male' },
        { value: 'female', label: 'Female' },
    ],
    DAYS: [
        { value: 1, label: 'Monday' },
        { value: 2, label: 'Tuesday' },
        { value: 3, label: 'Wednesday' },
        { value: 4, label: 'Thursday' },
        { value: 5, label: 'Friday' },
        { value: 6, label: 'Saturday' },
        { value: 0, label: 'Sunday' },
    ],
    CITY: [

    ]
}

export default SYSTEM_DATA
```

I have this kind of data file to keep constants but I need to fetch cities from server every time I opened the related page. How can I directly use my redux saga request here to fill CITY array.

Comment: create a reducer with these values as initial states and city as blank array. create action which updates cities array. in your cities fetch saga, on success dispatch that city update action with fetched value. but you have access those values from redux store only

Answer (score 0):

Could you just have this data in state and when your cities API request has resolved in your saga just fire an action to start the standard redux cycle.

```
// load SYSTEM_DATA into state or maybe just the cities part of that data

// saga runs
function* fetchCities() {
  const response = yield call(citiesApiCall)
  put(actions.updateCities, response)
}

// standard redux action/reducer cycle starts and completes updating your state CITY value
```

Call cities saga, call api, fire action with updated cities that then just goes through the standard redux action reducer process make a state change

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't just save your fetched data from server into you Store. Why you want to add something to const if you already have a Store as an option.

Call a store.dispatch(getCities()) in component that is on higher level or your components hierarchy.

So, 
In your high level component just dispatch an action and put all cities in your store "cities[]".

```
export function getAllCities(){
return fetch(YourUrl)
    .then(response=>response.json());}
```

and saga

```
export function* fetchCities(){

const cities=yield getAllCities();
yield put(putCitiesToStore(cities));}
```

In other hand, you can from this "getAllCities()" to fetch cities and add them to const.